# Share Extension Crash on reading Array from CoreData

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, swift, share

When I am trying to access my Array which is filled with data from CoreData. I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS Error.

Here is my Code:

```
var endPointList: Array<SettingsModel> = []

override func viewDidLoad() {

    var context = getManagedObjectContext()

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "SettingsEndpoint")
    endPointList = context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as [SettingsModel]

}
```

I get the Error when I press a button which triggers the following IBAction:

```
@IBAction func showEndPointAlert(){
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Endpunkte Auswahl", message: "Wählen sie einen Endpunkt", preferredStyle: .Alert)


    for endPoint : SettingsModel in endPointList {
         var endPointNameFromData:String = endPoint.name as String
    }

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Abbrechen", style: .Cancel) { (_) in }
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion:nil );
}
```

The debugger points to the following line:

```
var endPointNameFromData:String = endPoint.name as String
```

Strangely if I execute this code inside the viewDidLoad() method it runs. Why is this?

UPDATE:

Now with some edits from Mundi. I get a slightly different error:

```
2015-01-06 12:18:21.818 ShareExtension[1056:20857] 
-[SettingsModel name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6080000b2fc0
2015-01-06 12:20:24.755 ShareExtension[1056:20857] 
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '
-[SettingsModel name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6080000b2fc0'
```

My SettingsModel class:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

@objc(SettingsModel)
class SettingsModel: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var name:String
    @NSManaged var webservice:String
    @NSManaged var service:String

}
```

Comment: What's the debugger message when it breaks?

Answer (score 0):

When fetching from Core Data you usually need to cast the result to the correct type. Just declaring the variable of a certain type is not sufficient.

Preferably you should not be using `AnyObject` but a proper `NSManagedObject` subclass.

```
endPointList = context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as [EndPoint]
for endPoint : EndPoint in endPointList {
   println(endpoint.name)
}
```

Comment: It still breaks at println. But thanks for the advice.

Comment: Did you read your error message? It says your subclass must have a String attribute `name`. This is really a vary basic error that you should have caught. You should accept the answer as it solves the question you asked.

Comment: My subclass does have a String attribut called name

Comment: It means the object you assigned to your variable is not of type `SettingsModel`. *BTW: "SettingsModel" is not a very good name. Try "Settings".*

Comment: The code works in a different place. But not in the IBAction. Which means the type is correct.

Comment: It seems that you are narrowing down the problem. I suppose the rest of the debugging process is not suitable to run over SOF. Happy bug-fixing! :-)

Comment: That is not correct. You changed your question and your error message changed as well.

Comment: I got a more precise error message but the reason why I cant get the endPoint.name was the problem all along